how to multiply 4x in all operations
I would like to multiply the position size calculated by the strategy by 4.
The value of the position is 100 dollars so *4 = 400 dollars per position, if I lose 20 dollars, in the next position then the value will be 80 * 4, position 320 or if I win 80, the next position will be 180 * 4, 720.
In all positions, regardless of the value, it will always be multiplied by 4
multiplicadorCapital = input.float(4, title="Multiplicador do Capital Inicial", minval=0.5, step=0.5)
Entrada = strategy.equity*multiplicadorCapital
if enterLong
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, qty = Entrada)
alert("dispara Long")             `
I tried the strategies above and it didn't work
